# Returning a JSON response

Tags: java, json, curl, jersey

I'm learning REST services using the Jetty server, Jersey library and the JAX-RS.

I have the following method,which should return all Customer objects (in xml or json format):

```
    @GET
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    public Collection<Customer> getAll() {
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>(customerDB.values());
        return customerList;
    }
```

The customer objects is defined as:

```
package com.rest.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    // Maps a object property to a XML element derived from property name.
    @XmlElement
    public int id;
    @XmlElement
    public String firstname;
    @XmlElement
    public String lastname;
    @XmlElement
    public String email;
}
```

If I send the following command from curl I receive an xml response (instead of json, as requested):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8085/rest/customers/
```

Why is it returning an xml response, if I'm requesting json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `Content-Type:` header which refers to the content type you are sending to the server (which since it's a GET, you're not actually sending anything).  I think you might want to change that to an `Accept: application/json` header, which tells the server the type of response you'd like to receive.